# Redirecting user to iOS facebook app for authentication instead of browser window

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm fairly new to iOS Development and trying to use Facebook SDK for authentication for my app. I have done the integrations and whenever I click on the Login with Facebook button it opens a browser window in the app for authentication. How do I redirect the user to the inbuilt Facebook app which the user uses instead of a browser window if facebook is installed on the phone.

Comment: remove the URL schema in .plist

Comment: if the facebook app is installed the api login method will automatically redirect you to the facebook app, instead on the web browser page

Comment: goto setting> facebook and remove the userid-pwd, then check i think it will redirect on facebook app, and try on device not on simulator.

Comment: don't have URL schema defined in plist, running it on the device with facebook app installed and logged in

Answer (score 2):

In iOS9 it is not possible  switch with Facebook netive app .. For that you should try out other older version of Facebook sdk.

Please check below link.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/786729821439894/?search_id

Hope this will help you.

Link for Facebook sdk try it.

https://developers.facebook.com/resources/FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150708.pkg

Comment: Thanks, the link helped me

Comment: It's a win-win for facebook, less apps are used, they win, more people login with mobile safari, they win

Comment: @KaanSoral Happy to help you. Good luck.

Comment: @HemantSolanki the link for the facebook sdk you mentioned is broken, which older version would you suggest I use in order to get the app switching to work?